# CSS Bug on the Review Page

Tags: bug

I think there may be a bug on the review page of SO, as the Footer floats in the middle of the page and leaves a big white gap underneath it. This was checked on an iMac 2014 27inch, running the latest Safari version. Below is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]